# How to change values in XML file

Tags: scripts, files, xml

I have an XML file like below. I want change the values at default-value place of each argument name using a shell script like:

where argument name= protocol and default-value=tcp,
where argument name =port and default-value= 7223,
where argument name = username and default-value=test,

Example:

```
<task-arguments>
    <argument name="protocol" is-required="false" default-value="ssl"/>
    <argument name="port" is-required="true" default-value="7222"/>
    <argument name="username" is-required="true" default-value="admin"/>
</task-arguments>
```

Answer (score 4):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '/task-arguments/argument[@name="protocol"]/@default-value' -x 'string("tcp")' file.xml
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '/task-arguments/argument[@name="port"]/@default-value' -x 'string("7223")' file.xml
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '/task-arguments/argument[@name="username"]/@default-value' -x 'string("test")' file.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,,What is xmlstarlet ? is there any package should install in box

Comment: I have installed the smlstarlet package but still i am getting this error like   ./sed.sh: line 4: xmlstarlet: command not found
./sed.sh: line 5: xmlstarlet: command not found
./sed.sh: line 6: xmlstarlet: command not found

Comment: installed rpm version is [root@xxxxxxxxxxx test_xml]# rpm -ql xmlstarlet-0.5.1-19
/usr/bin/xml
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet/ChangeLog
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet/Copyright
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet/README
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet/TODO
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet/xmlstarlet.pdf
/usr/share/doc/packages/xmlstarlet/xmlstarlet.txt

Comment: It seems like you have installed old version. This community is only for Ubuntu related questions. Pls post the issue with `xmlstarlet` on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) community.